# FreeSSHD issue with home directory

Tags: ssh, freesshd

I’m hoping someone here can help out. I have everything working and I can successfully login through Putty, but the directory is C:\Windows\System32 and I can’t type anything. It’s frozen. I can successfully Putty into other servers and type, no problems. My home directory in FreeSSHD is set to C:\Test (I tried D:\Test as well) yet nothing works.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

open your freesshd configuration using the "right click" > "open as administrator".

when opening the app without that, your settings are not saved (even if it shows that they are).

it should work afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Try previous version 1.2.6. I have same bug in last version 1.2.7

And you can set option "Use new console engine" on ssh tab in this version. It's works.

But there is vulnerability in 1.2.6...
http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-4506/Freesshd.html

May be you can try Bitwise SSH server?